# hello i wanted to know why this code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wanted to know why this code doesn't work it simply does not inform anything enter the if and goes directly to the else

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

if(user.presence.activities !== null && user.presence.activities.type === 2 && user.presence.activities.name === 'Spotify' && user.presence.activities.assets !== null) {

    let trackIMG = `https://i.scdn.co/image/${user.presence.game.assets.largeImage.slice(8)}`;
    let trackURL = `https://open.spotify.com/track/${user.presence.game.syncID}`;
    let trackName = user.presence.activities.details;
    let trackAuthor = user.presence.activities.state;
    let trackAlbum = user.presence.activities.assets.largeText;

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Spotify Track Info', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/653135129870336031.png?v=1')
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setThumbnail(trackIMG)
        .addField('Song Name', trackName, true)
        .addField('Album', trackAlbum, true)
        .addField('Author', trackAuthor, false)
        .addField('Listen to Track', `${trackURL}`, false)
        .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp()

    message.channel.send(embed);
} else {
    message.channel.send('**Este usuário não está ouvindo o Spotify!**');
  }
}
```

Comment: Both if and else will not be executed as you might know , did you find any errors in console ?

Comment: Your if statement never executes because the condition uses `&&` meaning all conditions must be true, which they won't if you're checking if activities is null and right after also checking if activities.type is 2, change these operators to `||` meaning `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

*Common pitfalls*.

One thing you should keep in mind is there are chances the variable you are referring for may not be null always; it could be undefined, '': empty string, []: empty array etc.

null: this type is typically set by the user.

undefined: The rule of thumb is whenever you set manually never set it to undefined but null. Type "undefined" is usually set by the application/system. So if you set manually undefined, you maynot be aware whether it is set by the system or by the user.

```
// not recommended..
test = undefined;

// recommended..
test = null;
```

now, coming to your question, make sure that it is of the type youré referring to.

both user.presence.activities.assets and user.presence.activities are of type null and not undefined, '', [] etc..

validate as boolean:

```
!!user.presence.activities.assets
```

this will validate for

```
user.presence.activities.assets !== null
user.presence.activities.assets !== undefined
user.presence.activities.assets !== ''
```

if it's an array validate with JSON.stringify.

```
JSON.stringify(user.presence.activities.assets) !== '[]'
```

if it's an empty object, use the same to validate.

```
JSON.stringify(user.presence.activities.assets) !== '{}'
```

So, that being said, first console the values and write the relevent condition. eg:

```
const { presence: { activities } } = user;

if(!!activities && activities.type === 2 && 
activities.name === 'Spotify' && !!activities.assets) {
 // code..
}
```